# Como mostrar no template o caminho dos FileFields vinculados a um objeto específico?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, chave-estrangeira

Boa tarde!

Tenho uma aplicação web sendo feita no Django, e não sei como mostrar no template o caminho de todos os FileFields que estão vinculados a um objeto.

Possuo dois Models. Um para um formulário comum e o outro com uma chave estrangeira para vincular múltiplos arquivos, ficando salvos ao formulário (Solicitação e SolicitacaoDocumentos, respectivamente).

**A questão é que não sei como mostrar o caminho de TODOS OS ARQUIVOS que foram salvos em UM FORMULÁRIO ESPECÍFICO.**

Por exemplo:
Vou criar dois formulários, um chamado José da Silva e o outro Maria do Carmo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora vou adicionar 2 arquivos, um em cada formulário, através da minha outra classe (SolicitacaoDocumentos) que tem uma chave estrangeira.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Vamos ao Problema.**
Eu não sei como filtrar e mostrar no template somente os arquivos anexados, por  exemplo, a José da Silva ou a Maria do Carmo. O máximo que consegui foi listar todos anexos de todos formulários que tenho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class Solicitacao(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Solicitações'

    TIPO = (
        ('', ''),
        ('Internação Clínica', 'Internação Clínica'),
        ('Internação Cirúrgica', 'Internação Cirúrgica'),
        ('Internação Oncológica', 'Internação Oncológica'),
        ('Internação Cardiológica', 'Internação Cardiológica'),
        ('Internação Pediátrica', 'Internação Pediátrica'),
        ('Internação em UTI Pediátrica', 'Internação em UTI Pediátrica'),
        ('Internação em UTI Geral', 'Internação em UTI Geral'),
        ('Internação em UCO', 'Internação em UCO'),
        ('Internação em UTI Pediátrica', 'Internação em UTI Pediátrica'),
        ('Internação em UADC', 'Internação UADC'),
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    atendimento = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    carteira = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=TIPO, default=None, blank=False)
    observacao = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    definicoes = (
        ('Em análise', 'Em análise'),
        ('Internar', 'Internar'),
        ('Solicitar Transferência', 'Solicitar Transferência'),
    )

    definicao = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=definicoes, default=None, blank=False)
    setor = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nome)

def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join([instance.solicitacao.nome, instance.solicitacao.atendimento, filename])        

class SolicitacaoDocumentos(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Solicitações Documentos'

    solicitacao = models.ForeignKey(Solicitacao, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name='arquivo_chave')
    documentos = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.solicitacao.nome)
```

Urls.py

```
path('pav/<id>/', views.upload, name='upload'),
```

Views.py

```
def upload(request, id):

    arquivos = SolicitacaoDocumentos.objects.all()
    
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {
        'arquivos':arquivos
    })
```

Template:

```
{% for p in arquivos %}
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                {{ p.documentos }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Cara se tu tá querendo filtrar as 'SolicitacaoDocumentos' que esteja associado a um outro modelo no caso com 'Solicitacao', basta você usar o filter da seguinte forma.

Nessa view aqui:

Ao invés de colocar o all.

```
def upload(request, id):

arquivos = SolicitacaoDocumentos.objects.all()

return render(request, 'upload.html', {
    'arquivos':arquivos
})
```

Tu vai fazer dessa forma usando o filter

para importação do get_object_or_404

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def upload(request, id):
   solicitacao = get_object_or_404(Solicitacao, id=id)
   arquivos = SolicitacaoDocumentos.objects.filter(solicitacao = solicitacao)

return render(request, 'upload.html', {
    'arquivos':arquivos
})
```

Dai ele vai filtra todos as 'SolicitacaoDocumentos' que esteja relacionado com 'Solicitacao', e colocar em contexto.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa estou a disposição.
Espero está certo também.